# Form submit programmatically does not invoke inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I have the following autocomplete functions. The form gets autosubmitted when a one of suggested values is clicked:

```
var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {    
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val(ui.item.value);    
    var $form = $input.parents("form:first");    
    $form.submit();
};

var createAutoComplete = function () {    
    var $input = $(this);    
    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-source-autocomplete"),
        select: submitAutocompleteForm,
    };    
    $input.autocomplete(options);
};
$("input[data-source-autocomplete]").each(createAutoComplete);
```

This works just fine. The form has this additional hidden input:

```
<input id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" type="hidden" value="False" />
```

Now, I want change `submitAutocompleteForm` function to change this input's value to `true` upon submit:

```
$form.submit(function (e) {
    $(this).children('#autocomplete').val(true);
});
```

but this inner function is never invoked. Even tried with a simple `alert` inside, this also never gets invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Html code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadBook", new { id = Model.CollectionId }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "bookDetailsPlaceHolder",
    OnComplete = "animateBookLoad"
}))
{
    @Html.Hidden("autocomplete", false)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group form-custom">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBox("bookDetails", null, new { @class = "form-control pull-left", @placeholder = "Szukaj tytułu", data_source_autocomplete = Url.Action("Autocomplete") })
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="addCopySearchBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div id="bookDetailsPlaceHolder" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Also, I noticed that when I manually hit the `submit` button, the inner function gets invoked... So it seems to me that `$form.submit()` submits the form (obviously) but the `$form.submit(function () { }` actually gets invoked when the form is **being submitted**.

I'll try to specify whan I need:
I need the submitAutocompleteForm function to submit the value in TextBox, but also to change the hidden input's value. I cannot write something like `$('#form").on('submit', function () { }` as I do not want input's value to be changed when user manually submits the form.

Comment: At what point in your code are you adding the `$form.submit(fn)` event handler?

Comment: I do not want to add it, I just want the initial `$form.submit()` changed, so the input's value is changed.

Comment: please show your html code

Comment: Is $form equal to the same form you are submitting?

Comment: do you have any error in your console? I think that your variable `$form` is not defined.

Comment: No, I don't. Let me rephrase: I would like to change form's input value to `true` 'on the fly', while programatically submitting the form. Then, when the ajax call is finished, the initial form's input value remains `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('#autocomplete').val(true);
});
```

**This stops the form from sending** which means the function below will be able to manipulate the form elements. **However this means you do have to AJAX the form data via JavaScript or submit the form again**.

Comment: ... "AJAX the form data via JavaScript" ... or call the form's `submit` method.